# PHP: How to check in_array() for group of false keys?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an action to check. If it has been set false in $Actions I need to do stuff.

```
$Actions['edit'] => true;
$Actions['delete'] => false;
$Actions['foo'] => true;
$Actions['bar'] => false;

$actionToCheck = 'delete';
```

Attempt 1:

```
$falseActions = '???';

if ( in_array( $actionToCheck, $falseActions ) ) {
    //do stuff
}
```

Attempt 2:

```
if ( in_array( $actionToCheck, $Actions, false ) ) {
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do here.  It seems to me you know the array and you know the key you want to evaluate within the array, so it should be as simple as `if ($Actions[$actionToCheck]) { // do something if true }`

Comment: I have an action to check. If it has been set false in ´$Actions´ I need to do stuff.

Comment: Ok. Then `if (!$Actions[$actionToCheck]) { // do something if false}`

Comment: If you are trying to find out if `false` is in the `$Actions` array, then `in_array()` can do that, but it won't return the key value that is `false`.

Answer (score 1):

If I get what you are trying to do... How about :

```
foreach ($Actions AS $cSetting => $bValue) {
    if ($bValue === false) {
        print($cSetting . ' is false');
    }
}
```

this will allow you to do a targeted action against each setting that is false.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question correctly, it is a little vague.

The `in_array()` function checks to see if a value is in an array.  What you appear to be looking at is if a key exists.  You will need to use the `array_key_exists()` function.  Then once you have confirmed it, you can move forward with the rest of your code.

```
$Actions['edit'] => true;
$Actions['delete'] => false;

$actionToCheck = 'delete';

if(array_key_exists($actionToCheck, $Actions)) {
    //do stuff with the $Actions['delete'] value (which is 'false')
}
```

See more in the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php).

Comment: This would return true when ´$actionToCheck = 'edit';´ but it should only if the checked action has been set flase in ´$Actions`.

Comment: This will return true when `$actionToCheck` is equal to the key value of `$Actions` that you are looking at, which appears to be what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I notice you have multiple false values in your example. So:

```
<?php
if ($false_keys = array_keys($Actions, false, true)) {
    foreach ($false_keys as $action) {
        //do stuff with $action
    }
}
```

Your question is quite unclear...